# New columns into CSV file incredibly slow

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a bunch of .csv files and I'm trying to add in some new column headers and their values (which are all blank anyway) and then output this to a new .csv file. My script currently runs and works fine but it takes about 5 minutes to complete the operation on a 60MB file with about 70,000 rows - I have about 100 files to do this on so it will take a while using this script.
My code is below, it's quite simple but clearly inefficient!

```
Import-Csv $strFilePath |
    Select-Object *, @{Name='NewHeader';Expression={''}},
        @{Name='NewHeader2';Expression={''}},
        @{Name='NewHeader3';Expression={''}},
        @{Name='NewHeader4';Expression={''}} |
    Export-Csv $($strFilePath + ".new") -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Why not add ',newheader' to first line in file and ',""' to every other line?

Comment: the process of creating objects via `Import-CSV` can be quite slow. [*grin*] if all you want to do is add some columns to each data row, you can do that as _simple text objects_ instead of as _complex objects_ by using `Get-Content` - or by using the `StreamReader/StreamWriter` stuff. take a look here ... How to use the StreamReader class in Powershell to find and count number of characters contained in a file? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160052/how-to-use-the-streamreader-class-in-powershell-to-find-and-count-number-of-char

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, I think it would be better to treat it as a simple text without the useless conversion.

```
$path = 'C:\test'
$newHeaders = 'NewHeader1','NewHeader2','NewHeader3','NewHeader4'

$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Filter *.csv

$newHeadersString = @(''; $newHeaders | foreach { '"{0}"' -f $_ }) -join ','
$newColmunsString = ',""' * $newHeaders.Count

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $sr = $file.OpenText()
    $outfile = New-Item ($file.FullName + '.new') -Force
    $sw = [IO.StreamWriter]::new($outfile.FullName)

    $sw.WriteLine($sr.ReadLine() + $newHeadersString)
    while(!$sr.EndOfStream) { $sw.WriteLine($sr.ReadLine() + $newColmunsString) }

    $sr.Close()
    $sw.Close()
}
```